# TextField is hidden by keyboard inside of a Modal Bottom Sheet

Tags: flutter

I have several text fields. When I want to enter text, the keyboard is placed on these text fields. How can I make the keyboard move the Modal Bottom Sheet to the top of the keyboard?

[image]

Comment: Share this bottomsheet code with us

Comment: Set the 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' value in Scaffold to false.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the problem.I am facing this issue in latest flutter version and latest flutter_screenutil package.The problem is occured for inheritedMediaQuery which hide the content of the bottomsheet. if you are using flutter_screenutil maybe you are facing this issue.

so I just add

```
    ScreenUtilInit(
      useInheritedMediaQuery: true, // add this line and see the magic
      designSize: const Size(414, 896),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
    )
```

or if you don't use ScreenUtil then add line in MaterialApp

useInheritedMediaQuery: true, // add this line and see the magic

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you use the `SingleChildScrollView` widget and the ListView or Column widget to create the entire modal scrollable. This  can be allowed the content to be scrolled up, as the keyboard appears. And also, the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property can be used the  to automatically resize the modal, As the keyboard is displayed.

example code

```
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field 1'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, 
    );
  }
}
```